# embed tag auto downloading file text instead of only show

Tags: embed

I use , but some file make auto download

<embed
src={`${url}`}
/>
How to prevent it? I was try some way for like file PDF but it not success
link: https:// betterprogramming.pub/how-to-display-pdfs-but-prevent-them-from-downloading-in-react-2e77292ca9a5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.